# Inner Join Ambiguous Error Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query, inner-join, postgresql-10

```
Select * from "EstoqueCultura" 
Inner Join "Cultura" on "Cultura"."Id" = "EstoqueCultura"."CulturaId"
Inner Join "Estoque" on "Estoque"."ClienteId" ="EstoqueCultura"."ClienteId"
where "ClienteId" = 7957   

//// O ERRO ////
ERROR:  column reference "ClienteId" is ambiguous
LINE 4: where "ClienteId" = 7957 
              ^
SQL state: 42702
Character: 185
```

Comment: Qualifique o campo ...where "Estoque"."ClienteId" = 7957

Answer (score 1):

Conforme mencionado antes, você deve informar de qual tabela o campo `ClienteId` deverá ser referenciado, neste caso o SGBD não sabe resolver de qual tabela ele deve utilizar para usar dentro do `where`.

```
Select * from "EstoqueCultura" 
Inner Join "Cultura" on "Cultura"."Id" = "EstoqueCultura"."CulturaId"
Inner Join "Estoque" on "Estoque"."ClienteId" ="EstoqueCultura"."ClienteId"
where "EstoqueCultura.ClienteId" = 7957
```

[Material para referência](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_ref_join.asp)